# Generate addresses without private key: Stealth addresses vs Master Public Key

Tags: electrum, public-key, address-generation, bip32-hd-wallets, stealth-address

In my case a store owner has different POS terminals. On none of the terminals should be a private key stored! The owner has one wallet, where he wants to get all transactions aggregated, done on the POS terminals.

According to my reasearch I came up with 2 possibilities:

- Stealth addresses (BIP 63), which to my knowledge is not implemented anywhere in a library, so that I could use it easily.
- Master Public Key: E.g. the electrum wallet gives you an MPK by which one could derive addresses (through HD Derivation).

Now to my questions:

- Is there any other approach one could generate addresses without a private key available?
- Are there any problems one could face with the MPK derivation approach?
- Which wallets expose the MPK and furthermore which wallets get a notice of transactions done to addresses derived outside of their knowledge (however from the seed they know)?

Comment: Of course, there is always the naive approach where you generate one single address (or one per terminal) and use that address for all incoming transactions.  I assume that for improved anonymity (both for your store owner and the customers), you wish to avoid this?

Comment: @NateEldredge Or improved auditability.

Comment: @NateEldredge absolutely, reusing the same address should be avoided!

Comment: @NickODell Auditing is not an issue in my case, as the orders are stored in a POS system, only the payments should go via bitcoin.

Comment: Just checking, if you are still looking you can try https://medium.com/@blockonomics_co/payment-companion-for-your-wallet-dc3766b14e7a#.sh1h017gy. Can generate address/invoice using ur MPK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Electrum describes as 'Master Public Keys' are more commonly know as 'extended public keys' and are an excellent way for a Point of Sale terminal to accept payment without being able to spend that payment.

> Is there any other approach one could generate addresses without a private key available?

Well, there's always the approach of generating all of your addresses in advance. That has the advantage of simplicity. Other than that, I don't think there are any other approaches which work as well as BIP32.

> Are there any problems one could face with the MPK derivation approach?

You mentioned that you have *multiple* terminals, which means that you need to avoid using the same index with the same MPK , or you'll generate the same address. You can avoid this by either using different indexes, or different MPK's.

> Which wallets expose the MPK and furthermore which wallets get a notice of transactions done to addresses derived outside of their knowledge (however from the seed they know)?

Electrum does this. It's called a 'gap limit.' It will check for transactions beyond the last address with a balance that it knows about. By default it only checks 5 extra addresses, but you can increase that. Having an adjustable gap limit is pretty common.